# Tries in batch file not working on password entry

Tags: batch-file

I need this file to give you 3 tries to enter a password and if not then shutdown or shut down any way 60 secs after the first failed attempt 
please help

here is the batch file

```
@echo off
color 02
set /a %tries%== 4
set /p %password%== Mike.1587
taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe
shutdown -s -t 60000
goto MAIN-LAUNCH

:MAIN-LAUNCH
cls
if %tries%==0 goto DEATH-OVERRIDE-SHUTDOWN
title Locked by %username%
echo Enter Password Before Time Runs Out... 
echo You have %tries% tries left 
set /p password= 
if %password%==Mike.1587 goto IF-TRUE 
if not /p password=Mike.1587 goto NOT-TRUE 


:NOT-TRUE 
%tries% -1
echo Incorrect Password Try Again...
echo You have %tries% left
echo Press any key to try again. . .
pathping localhost -q 2 -p 3500> nul
goto MAIN-LAUNCH


:IF-TRUE
echo Correct!
start explorer.exe
shutdown -a
pathping localhost -q 2 -p 1000> nul
exit

DEATH-OVERRIDE-SHUTDOWN
shutdown.exe /s /t 00
exit
```

Comment: `if not /p password=Mike.1587 goto NOT-TRUE ` this `/p` is not from `if` syntax .Probably a copy-paste from the `set /p` ? And need double =

Comment: don't use == for assignments, prepend all ypur labels with :, use set /a for calculations is tead of expecting cmd to know what ypu mean with %tries%-1, don't use copy & paste without looking, …

Comment: oh, another one:`set /a %tries%== 4` should be `set tries=4` etc. really, there's so much wrong with this, it's probably better if you start out by learning to code batch scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. A lot of your batch syntax is incorrect. I would recommend you go to a basic tutorial online before you start your next project.

```
@echo off
color 02
set /a tries=3
set /p P=Mike.1587
taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe
shutdown -s -t 60000

:: Start
:Attempt
cls
if "%tries%"=="0" goto Fail
title Locked by %username%
echo Enter Password Before Time Runs Out... 
echo You have %tries% tries left 
set /p "password=Password: "
if "%password%"=="%P%" goto Correct

:: Wrong Password
set /a tries-=1
echo Incorrect Password Try Again...
echo You have %tries% left
echo Press any key to try again. . .
pathping localhost -q 2 -p 3500> nul
goto Attempt

:Correct
shutdown -a
echo Correct!
start explorer.exe
pathping localhost -q 2 -p 1000> nul
exit

:Fail
shutdown.exe /s /t 00
exit
```